# Best Practice for trimming content in Sharepoint Hosted Apps?

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

*This is a copy of the same [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1d602955-457b-4c75-bb51-e6ae2c5f75a6/best-practice-for-trimming-content-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps?forum=sharepointdevelopment) I made over on the Sharepoint forums - haven't gotten a single response.  :(*

I'm developing a Sharepoint 2013 App that is set to be Sharepoint Hosted.  I have a section within the app that I'd like to be Configuration-related, so I would like to only allow certain users or roles to be able to access this content or even see that it exists (i.e. an Admin button, if you will).  What is the best practice for accomplishing this in Sharepoint 2013 Apps?  Thusfar, I've been doing everything using jQuery and the REST api and I'm hoping there's a standard within this that I should be using.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can weigh in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually develop the SP 2013 App and all my apps using the EffectiveBasePermissions property of the List or Web to check the user has the appropriate permissions. Ex: If the user is an administrator, check the permission kind is manage web. Or you can check the permission of a user in a list can add/edit/delete. By this way, you can show or hide the admin button or the appropriate actions for an user.
See below links for the detail of PermissionKind:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556747(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556747%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Let's me know if you need more about that.

Comment: This makes sense, I think.  So in the context of the App Web for a Sharepoint Hosted App, what would a RESTful call look like for just checking the logged-in user's effective base permission of the app web - like the manage web permission check?

Comment: First, you have to load EffectiveBasePermission property for web or list you want to check the permission. Once the execute asyc is succeeded, you can check the permission of the user by PermissionKind. Here is a link similar with that but it's checking the permission for a list item: [link](http://www.novolocus.com/2012/02/29/check-permissions-in-javascript-client-object-model/)